# How to get through the Google+ AP list of persons in my circles BUT of my business page - not in my account

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I'm successfully reading persons in my circles in main, personal google account (via [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)). But I have a few business pages - as a part of personal google account. I would like to read list persons in my circles of this pages.

When I'm trying below code **with $userId 'me'** it works fine. But when I'm trying the code with **my bussiness page ID** as $userID I receive error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/101474958426407069227/people/visible: (400) Only allowed to fetch the authenticated user's visible circles.'

**Code**

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);

...

$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
$people= $plus->people->listPeople('me','visible');  <-- That works
$people= $plus->people->listPeople('101474958426407069227','visible');  <-- That DOES NOT work although 101474958426407069227 is my bussiness page connected with my main google account.
```

How can I do it? Is there any additional method of authenticating pages (not main account)?

Answer (score 0):

[People: list](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/list) List all of the people in the specified collection.

[About Google+ pages](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1710600?hl=en) Google+ pages provide local businesses, brands, organizations and artists with a public identity and presence on Google+. Google+ pages are managed through the Google My Business dashboard, which allows businesses to update and share business information on Google.

So Pages are not People.  Pages have not been exposed though the Google+ api.  You cant do this at this time. You can probably find a number of issue quests asking for this to be added to the api.  Google-plus-platform [issues](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list)